# Blender random theme gen

Tags: python, xml, themes, blender

written below is script to form random hex string. The issue at hand is that it always prints identical result when called. Hex tag does not change periodically that randinteger indicate. 
How to resolve?

```
import bpy
from random import randint

a=["a","b","c","d","e","f","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]
b=["a","b","c","d","e","f","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]
c=["a","b","c","d","e","f","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]
d=["a","b","c","d","e","f","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]
e=["a","b","c","d","e","f","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]
f=["a","b","c","d","e","f","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]


hex='"'+"#"+str(a[randint(0,15)])+str(b[randint(0,15)])+str(c[randint(0,15)])+str(d[randint(0,15)])+str(e[randint(0,15)])+str(f[randint(0,15)])+'"'

def xmlScript():
    global hex
    print("<bpy>")
    print("  <Theme>")
    print("    <view_3d>")
    print("      <ThemeView3D object_active="+hex)   
    print("                   editmesh_active="+hex)
    print("                   act_spline="+hex)
    print("                   handle_align="+hex)
    print("                   handle_sel_align="+hex)
    print("                   handle_auto="+hex)

xmlScript()
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an.. *interesting* way to generate a random 24 bit number.  Of course the issue is that you generate `hex` once at module-level, not on the fly as needed.

Try something like this instead:

```
from random import randint

def rand_24bit():
     return '"#{:x}"'.format(randint(0,16**6-1))
```

This uses [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) to format a random 24-bit integer into hex.  demo:

```
rand_24bit()
Out[22]: '"#118656"'

rand_24bit()
Out[23]: '"#abb6c4"'

rand_24bit()
Out[24]: '"#1c2e5c"'
```